# cmd programming batch file for loop

Tags: batch-file

I am new to this but I was trying to make a batch file that would copy name of the executable file in specific location , create a new folder, give it same name as file , copy the executable file in that folder and run it.

I got all this worked out but I have more than one .exe files and I was wondering how to carry out all these iterations for all the files in the location

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for` to iterate over files:

```
for %%F in (*.exe) do (
  mkdir "C:\Foo\%%~nF"
  copy "%%F" "C:\Foo\%%~nF"
  "C:\Foo\%%F"
)
```

Comment: @user1452157 If this fully answers your question, please accept it.

Comment: Joey, thanks it worked really well , ia had one more question in that, how can we calculate execution time in that program that can be displayed at the end of the execution, please help - thank you once again

Comment: Ask a separate question for that.